# RNSScreen error when using @react-navigation/bottom-tabs

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, node-modules

I'm getting RNSScreen error in React Native. I started getting this error after using the @react-navigation/bottom-tabs package. I will write the methods I use in order:

`npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

After doing this the error still persists. This is not the solution to the error. I downloaded the packages again in the new project and tried, but the error still persisted.

I re-downloaded node_modules but it didn't work. As a last resort, I applied here. Thank you in advance for your help.

**My Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import PostSayfasi from './screens/PostSayfasi';
import AyarlarSayfasi from './screens/AyarlarSayfasi';
import BildirimlerSayfasi from './screens/BildirimlerSayfasi';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerHome}>
    <StatusBar
        backgroundColor="#A47C66"
        barStyle="light-content"
        translucent={false} 
      />
      <View style={styles.titleArea}>
        <Image style={styles.logoImage} src='https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEgzh5Hj6pT9844BcFUKrHInacviJGZKxliC5xDUCYE_e57XkpeKkKdvSaaVCAO00yW58LrBb8tayvglL0N3oNLCrkB-UlfzHL0AAkXKc7HXiH8Nj172hYIeOUx59bZj8Y72U1Z3bk4gVE4iUQKOVXw4nhDBZ2n4esWtH9s3-KDto7R63JDmqHfzIUWEgGD4/s1600/rafhane_logo.png'/>
      </View>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name='Ayarlar' component={AyarlarSayfasi}/>
          <Tab.Screen name='Postlar' component={PostSayfasi}/>
          <Tab.Screen name='Bildirimler' component={BildirimlerSayfasi}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerHome:{
    backgroundColor: '#f8f5f3',
    flex:1,
  },
  titleArea:{
    padding: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    elevation: 2
  },
  logoImage:{
    width: '50%', 
    height: 40,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }
});

export default App;
```

`npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

After doing this the error still persists. This is not the solution to the error. I downloaded the packages again in the new project and tried, but the error still persisted.

I re-downloaded node_modules but it didn't work. As a last resort, I applied here. Thank you in advance for your help.